# When to use ShouldSerializeXXX vs. XmlIgnoreAttribute for XML serialization

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have looked for examples to ignore a property of a class during xml serialization and deserialization. I have found three different methods and can't figure out, when they should be used. My special interest is, which one works with [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) better.

1. [`XmlIgnore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute

   ```cs
   public class Item
   {
       [XmlIgnore]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Method beginning with `ShouldSerialize...`

   ```cs
   public class Item
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public bool ShouldSerializeName()
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
3. [`NonSerialized`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute

   ```cs
   public class Item
   {
       [NonSerialized]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Where there is some explanation about the difference between `XmlIgnoreAttribtue` and `NonSerializedAttribute` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201658/difference-between-nonserialized-and-xml-serialization-xmlignore) and [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6), I was not able to find information about when to use `XmlIgnoreAttribtue` and when the `ShouldSerializeXXX` pattern. I tried both of them with the XmlSerializer and both of them see work as expected.

Comment: If they all work to your standard, then choose the one you prefer. PS The `ShouldSerializeXXX` version is an awful idea, don't use that one!

Comment: @DavidG: Con you please argument why is it an awful idea to use `ShouldSerializeXXX`.

Comment: Well you're going to pollute your model with all those extra methods whereas an attribute won't.

Comment: Another reason to not use ShouldSerializeXXX is after implementing all of that, what happens when someone later comes in and needs to change the name of the field.  That task now broke serialization without the developer being aware of it.

Comment: XmlSerializer doesn't seem to have a ContractResolver like JSON.net, which leaves ShouldSerialize as the only way to dynamically include/exclude members. We use a T4 template to generate the ShouldSerializeXxxx functions. We have so many properties the generated file is 10,000 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic difference between #1 and #2 is that they generate different *[XML Schemas](https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/schema)*.  If you want a member to be excluded from your type's schema, use [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx).  If you want a member to be included conditionally, use [`ShouldSerializeXXX()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx) or [`XXXSpecified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx).  (Finally, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201658/difference-between-nonserialized-and-xml-serialization-xmlignore), [`[NonSerialized]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) in option #3 is ignored by `XmlSerializer`.)

To see the difference between #1 and #2, you can use [`xsd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) to generate schemas for your types.  The following schema is generated for version #1 and completely omits the `Name` member:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="Item" />
```

While the following for #2 conditionally includes the `Name` member:

```xml
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
```

The difference arises because `XmlSerializer` and `xsd.exe` both perform *static type analysis* rather than *dynamic code analysis*.  Neither tool can determine that the `Name` property in case #2 will always be skipped, because neither tool attempts to decompile the source code for `ShouldSerializeName()` to prove it always returns `false`.  Thus `Name` will appear in the schema for version #2 despite never appearing in practice.  If you then create a web service and publish your schema with [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) (or simply make them available manually), different clients will be generated for these two types -- one without a `Name` member, and one with.

An additional complexity can arise when the property in question is of a non-nullable value type.  Consider the following three versions of `Item`.  Firstly, a version with an unconditionally included value property:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Generates the following schema with `Id` always present:

```xml
  <xs:complexType name="Item">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Secondly, a version with an unconditionally excluded value property:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Generates the following schema that completely omits the `Id` property:

```xml
  <xs:complexType name="Item" />
```

And finally a version with a conditionally excluded value property:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeId()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Generates the following schema with `Id` only conditionally present:

```xml
  <xs:complexType name="Item">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Schema #2 is as expected, but notice there is a difference between #1 and #3: the first has `minOccurs="1"` while the third has `minOccurs="0"`.  The difference arises because `XmlSerializer` is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx) to skip members with `null` values by default, but has no similar logic for non-nullable value members.  Thus the `Id` property in case #1 will always get serialized, and so `minOccurs="1"` is indicated in the schema.  Only when conditional serialization is enabled will `minOccurs="0"` be generated.  If the third schema is in turn used for client code generation, an `IdSpecified` property will be added to the auto-generated code to track whether the `Id` property was actually encountered during deserialization:

```
public partial class Item {

    private int idField;

    private bool idFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IdSpecified {
        get {
            return this.idFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.idFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For more details on binding to conditionally serialized value members, see [XML Schema Binding Support: MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx) and [ShouldSerialize*() vs *Specified Conditional Serialization Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838640/3744182).

So that's the primary difference, but there are secondary differences as well that may influence which you choose:

- `[XmlIgnore]` cannot be overridden in a derived class, but `ShouldSerializeXXX()` can be when marked as virtual; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592671/3744182) for an example.
- If a member cannot be serialized by `XmlSerializer` because, for instance, it refers to a type that [lacks a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor), then marking the member with `[XmlIgnore]` will allow the containing type to be serialized - while adding a `ShouldSerializeXXX() { return false; }` will NOT allow the containing  type to be serialized, since as stated previously `XmlSerializer` only performs static type analysis.  E.g. the following:

  ```
   public class RootObject
   {
       // This member will prevent RootObject from being serialized by XmlSerializer despite the fact that the ShouldSerialize method always returns false.
       // To make RootObject serialize successfully, [XmlIgnore] must be added.
       public NoDefaultConstructor NoDefaultConstructor { get; set; }

       public bool ShouldSerializeNoDefaultConstructor() { return false; }
   }

   public class NoDefaultConstructor
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public NoDefaultConstructor(string name) { this.Name = name; }
   }
  ```

  cannot be serialized by `XmlSerializer`.
- `[XmlIgnore]` is specific to `XmlSerializer`, but `ShouldSerializeXXX()` is used by other serializers including [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) and [protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190167/protobuf-net-conditional-serialization).
- As mentioned in comments, renaming a conditionally serialized property in Visual Studio does not automatically rename the corresponding `ShouldSerializeXXX()` method name, leading to potential maintenance gotchas down the road.